# How to place only one symbol on the centroid of a multipart polygon?

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, multipart

I am using QGIS version 2.14.1 (Essen). I would like to place symbols on the centroids of my data. The problem is that some of my data has multi-part polygons, which means it places the symbol at the centroid of each mutlipart.

Is there anyway to place a unique symbol at the centroid of the polygon even if the geometry is a multi-part?

It works fine for single part geometries but not for multiparts.

Comment: At the risk of sounding obvious, can't you convert your layer to singleparts polygons?

Comment: I didnt really think of that because some multi part geometry is quite complex which emans the centroid would be false but if thats the only solution then i can try. How do I do this?

Comment: Simply with Vector > Geometry tools > Multipart to Singleparts.

Comment: This doesnt work....I also tried editing directly the geometry but i have so much data its impossible to do manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature <del>[is currently being evaluated](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/3026) to be integrated with QGIS 2.16 (and has good chances that it will be)</del> will be part of QGIS with the 2.16 release and present on master builds from after Apr, 29 2016.

For a solution compatible with 2.14 see below.

[image]

[image]

Or if you want to use QGIS 2.14, use a Geometry Generator symbol layer.

```
CASE WHEN @geometry_part_num = 1 THEN centroid($geometry)
ELSE NULL
END CASE
```

(Sorry, not on a proper machine to verify this expression right now, it may be slightly different or more complicated, but there certainly is a possibility with a similar approach)

Comment: Is there a way to create the centroid for the biggest geometry part? Otherwise the geom generator result might be rather suboptimal.

Comment: In the pull request, this is what is currently being discussed (tends towards: yes). With Geometry Generator probably also using `order_parts( $geometry, 'area($geometry)', False )` and then only rendering the first part.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn Thanks for your help! Do you know when this new feature will be released? It is exactly what I am needing

Comment: Release will be 2.16 (End of June) if you are not afraid of using development versions, a couple of days (or hours?). Note: this has not been officially merged yet, so no guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

This lacking feature / bug is known and reported at https://hub.qgis.org/issues/9199

For now, you could create a centroid point layer, remove potential unwanted points and symbolize that.

Comment: Yes I think that is what I am going to do but I have so many data points that it might take a long time!